# Objects in array turn into undefined after using a particular reducer/action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working with a classic *to do list* project to learn Redux and I'm having a strange issue.

Basically, I have a to-do list with checkboxes and when the user clicks on a checkbox, an action gets dispatched which should mark that object's completed property as true and the component should update.

However... When this action fires, the object which is supposed to be marked as complete successfully returns with all of it's properties but the rest of the todo list (the other objects in the array) get corrupted, losing all their properties and they turn into 'undefined' thus causing problems in the render.

I've tried to include all the code that I think is relevant but I think that I'm doing something wrong in my reducer, but I can't find seem to find the issue.

**Todo List Component**

```
class TodoList extends Component {

    render(){
        const {todos, showCompleted, searchTerm} = this.props;
        const renderTodos = () => {
            if (todos.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <p className="container__message">Nothing to do.</p>
                );
            }
            return TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchTerm).map((todo) => {
                return (
                    <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>
                );
            });
        };
        return (
             <div>
                 {renderTodos()}
             </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect((state) => {
    return state;
})(TodoList);
```

**Todo Component**

```
class Todo extends Component {

    render() {
        const {id, text, completed, createdAt, completedAt, dispatch} = this.props;
        const todoClass = completed
            ? 'todo todo-completed'
            : 'todo';

        const renderDate = () => {
            let displayMessage = 'Created ';
            let timestamp = createdAt;

            if (completed) {
                displayMessage = 'Completed ';
                timestamp = completedAt;
            }
            return displayMessage + moment.unix(timestamp).format('MMM Do YYYY @ h:mm a');
        };

        return (
            <div className={todoClass}
                onClick={event => dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id)) }>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} readOnly/>
                <div>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    <p className="todo__subtext">{renderDate()}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect()(Todo);
```

**Action**

```
export const toggleTodo = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
        id: id
    };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export const todosReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
        return state.map((todo) => {
            if (todo.id === action.id) {
                let nextCompleted = !todo.completed;

                return {
                    ...todo,
                    completed: nextCompleted,
                    completedAt: todo.completed ? moment().unix() : 0
                };
            }
        });
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you are not `returning` anything if the `condition todo.id === action.id` fail. With the `map` if you don't `return` anything, by default it will `return` `undefined`, Try this:

```
return state.map((todo) => {
    if (todo.id === action.id) {
        let nextCompleted = !todo.completed;

        return {
            ...todo,
            completed: nextCompleted,
            completedAt: todo.completed ? moment().unix() : 0
        };
    }else{
        return todo;
    }
});
```

Check this:

```js
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
b = a.map ( i => { if(i % 2 == 0) return i;})
console.log(b);
```

Comment: That explains! The else statement solves the issue entirely and I see why thanks to your answer.

Comment: Of course, I was waiting for the time limit to expire.